# Form closes with an error when working with the database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to make it so that when changing the value in the comboBox, the database is displayed in the dataGridview. Everything seems to work, but when you close the form it gives an error:
enter image:

[image]

Code:

```
namespace Cursach
{
    public partial class VoucherForm : Form
    {
        public VoucherForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void VoucherCountry()
        {
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowDrop = false;
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

            DB dB = new DB();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Voucher WHERE Name_Country= @nC", dB.ConnectionSQL());
            command.Parameters.Add("@nC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            dB.OpenSQL();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dB.ClodeSQL();
        }


        private void VoucherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.countryTableAdapter.Fill(this.cursacDat.Country);
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VoucherCountry();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you having value in `comboBox1.SelectedValue` ? If value is not there means, supply hard-coded value to see data coming from DB.

Comment: Add `If(this.IsDisposed) return;` as first line in the `VoucherCountry` method.

Comment: @JQSOFT I tried to add, but the error remained

Comment: Then replace it with `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0) return;` or `if(comboBox1.SelectedValue == null) return;` and try.

Comment: @sriharsha  The value in comboBox1 is the countries that are available in the database. By selecting a value in comboBox the dataGridview should display information about this country

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes, everything works now. Thanks

Comment: Well done mate. Happy new year.

Comment: @JQSOFT I was a bit confused by your comment `If(this.IsDisposed) return;`. If the Form was disposed how would the code be running?

Comment: @Mary When he closes the Form, the combo's items are cleared and the `SelectedIndex` resets to it's default value (-1) hence the event is fired (if an item was selected) one last time and calls that function. `IsDisposed` property exists to indicate an object _is being disposed_. So in this case, it returns `true` if you call it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event or as the first line in the method. However, in this context, checking the `SelectedIndex` is better. Happy new year.

Comment: @JQSOFT Tried it by putting code in SelectIncesChanged and closing the Form. The code didn't run. A Very Happy New Year to you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `DB` class which is good to separate you database code from your user interface code. I moved the database code to retrieve the Country data to the `DB` class. Notice how the `DB` class knows nothing about the user interface and the user interface knows nothing about the database.

Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `using` blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error.

```
    public class DB
    {
        private string ConStr = "Your connection string";

        public DataTable GetCountryData(string nC)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Voucher WHERE Name_Country= @nC", cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@nC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = nC;
                cn.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Then in the form.

```
    private void OpCode()
    {
         if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a value in the drop down.");
            return;
         }
        DB DataClass = new DB();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataClass.GetCountryData(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes, you are so right. Can't call `.ToString` on a null! I like the `SelectIndex >= 0` Thanks for pointing that out.